# How to owerride the 'show' template in the new version of Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin

How can I override the 'show' template in the new version of Sonata Admin? Before I extended in my template the base template:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show.html.twig' %}
```

and overriden:

```
{% block show_field %} my content {% endblock %}.
```

But now this does not work. What template do I need to extend now?

P.S. I want to override a template only for one entity, so global override is not a solution for me.

Comment: Please specify in your question which version of Symfony and which version of SonataAdminBundle you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony version: 4.1.*

SonataAdmin version: ^3.39

This how I do it:

In `config/services.yaml`

```
admin.invoice:
    class: App\Admin\InvoiceAdmin
    arguments: [~, App\Entity\Invoice, ~]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: invoice, label_catalogue: App, label_translator_strategy: sonata.admin.label.strategy.noop }
    calls:
        - [ setTemplate, [show, "InvoiceAdmin/show.html.twig"]]            
    public: true
```

Then I copy `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Resources/views/CRUD/base_show.html.twig` to `templates/InvoiceAdmin/show.html.twig`.

Answer (score 0):

Try if the **base_show_macro** template is what you are looking for:

```
vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/base_show_macro.html.twig
```

or in twig:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_macro.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: No this not work, because base_show_macro not extend base_show. base_show_macro.html.twig impoted in variable show_helper [code](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/Resources/views/CRUD/base_show.html.twig#L14) and render in some places [code](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/Resources/views/CRUD/base_show.html.twig#L59). Before this block show_field was in base_show [code](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/commit/fd1a1596f86bfb4afdafe9767efaa4c787bba6a5#diff-0cb97fb894cd897069cbade4ba839c97L36)